# Departure And Returned Date

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

```
   function CompareDate( epr_departuredate,epr_returneddate) {
    var epr_departuredate = new Date(24,11,2016); //Today Date
   var epr_returneddate = new Date(25,11,2016);
   if (epr_departuredate >epr_returneddate) {

        alert("Departure Date  Cannot Late Than Return Date. Please Check");
    }else {
        alert("Date You Enter is Valid. Please Continue.");
    }
}
```

Why my code doesn't work, it only display:

> Departure Date  Cannot Late Than Return Date. Please Check.

when I run. I just want to compare departure date and  returned date.

Comment: It's `new Date(year, month[, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);` [[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this:

```
function CompareDate( epr_departuredate,epr_returneddate) {
    epr_departuredate="2017/05/28";//say it is string and pass this value when call the function
    epr_returneddate="2017/05/29"
    var departuredate = new Date(epr_departuredate); //Today Date
    var returneddate = new Date(epr_returneddate);
   if (departuredate >returneddate) {

        alert("Departure Date  Cannot Late Than Return Date. Please Check");
    }else {
        alert("Date You Enter is Valid. Please Continue.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. sadly its  still display the second condition even when i wrongly enter the date.

Comment: Could you please tell me when you call CompareDate function which date format have  you used

Comment: @typo because you need to remove the lines assigning fixed values (done for testing only) and pass correct values to the function.

Comment: @typo if it is helpful,please accept it as an answer

Comment: still face the same error. but then thanks for ur answer

Comment: Date     <input type="date" name="epr_departuredate" id="epr_departuredate" maxlength="50" size="18" />   

  Date <input type="date" name="epr_returneddate" id="epr_returneddate" maxlength="50" size="18" >



 <input name="btnAdd" type="button" id="btnAdd" value="check" onClick = "CompareDate()" src = "e_adv_new.asp">


 I tried to call compare date function at this code.